# Python Pillow HSV color selection; making it more specific

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a webapp that would allow you to edit images using colors, for example coloring a black and white image or switching a color of a car in a colored image.

My first approach of color selection was sampling the color in rgb and then working from there. The problem is with rgb the color variation is so large that selecting like shades of purple from an image you can end up reselecting multiple times and still have little boxes where you still haven't sampled it. For example here's the original image:

[image]

Using the [webapp](http://pixelart.thecoderr.com/color-editor) I select a small box region between the image to sample colors and then showing where colors matched below

[image]

you can tell it has that small box region and little spots outside where the color matches.

I did some research and found that HSV which is Hue, Saturation and Value is an easier way to select shades of colors.

So using the same method the webapp provides a region of interest, I as usual get the area of interest and then if using hsv get the hue value of the area of interest and use it to check on the image, all the pixels with the same hue value and this is returned as the new selection area and it's used to then sample all these new pixels for colors.

This is the code below

```
def get_hsv_positions(image, positions):
    #hsv comes in hue (color of image), saturation and value that's supposed to be how light or dark the color is
    hsv_image = image.convert('HSV')

    values = []

    for pixel in positions:
        values.append(hsv_image.getpixel(tuple(pixel)))

    hues = set([x[0] for x in values])
    hue_matches = []

    width, height = image.size

    img_width, img_height = 0,0

    for _ in range(width * height):
        if img_width == width:
            img_height += 1
            img_width = 0

        pixel = hsv_image.getpixel((img_width, img_height))
        if pixel[0] in hues:
            hue_matches.append((img_width, img_height))

        img_width += 1

    return hue_matches

def get_color_range(request):
    ...

    #this gets the x,y position on the image of interest to sample colors
    cells = []
    for item in selection:
        pos = get_position(item['position']['left'], item['position']['top'], image.width, image.height, width, height)
        item['position']['top'] = pos[1]
        item['position']['left'] = pos[0]

        scale_grid(item, width, height, image.width, image.height)
        cells.extend(get_cells(item))

    image = PILImage.open(image_url)

    if hsv:
        cells = get_hsv_positions(image, cells)
```

and this is how it samples the image now

[image]

it's better but not perfect as you can tell here

### Original Image Sampling Skin Color

[image]

### Sampling using HSV

[image]

### Sampling Without Using HSV

[image]

As you can tell HSV get's more of those small tones that pop up as small shapes on the image but doesn't get all of them.

I'm hoping someone who's played around with image manipulation whether for data science or something else might help.

Also this is an open source project I made and work on in my spare time, so if you're interested you can checkout the [source code](https://github.com/six-wars/pixelart) , here's a [quick intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSpVxtOC-00) video on how it works. So if you want to contribute to it, you know the channels :) or use it for free, whatever works for you.

Comment: Some directions to try (but not a full answer): With the second picture (or for your "car" idea), it sort of looks like segmentation might help. Have you looked at opencv's "watershed"? Also, the sections that you missed are kind of square, which makes me think they might be JPEG compression related and an edge-aware Gaussian filter might help.

Comment: Anything in HSV colourspace often goes mad and blocky after being subjected to JPEG compression - I think it may have something to do with chroma down-sampling but have never really explored it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that comes to mind is to blur the hue channel of your image when picking pixels in the range. That should smooth out abrupt changes in hue (i.e. the boxy artifacts from the portrait).

One way to do that would be to convert the hue channel to a numpy array, apply a Gaussian filter, and then use it to create a mask. This is a rough rewrite of your `get_hsv_positions` function that uses numpy and scipy instead of loops.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

def get_hsv_positions_smooth(image, positions):
    #hsv comes in hue (color of image), saturation and value that's supposed to be how light or dark the color is
    hsv_image = image.convert('HSV')

    # convert to numpy array
    hsv_image = np.array(hsv_image)
    hue_channel = hsv_image[0, :, :]  # indexed (channel, row, column)

    # get the matching hues
    matching_hues = set()
    for x,y in positions:
        matching_hues.add(hue_channel[x, y])

    # blur hue channel
    SIGMA = 2
    blurred_hue = gaussian_filter(hue_channel, SIGMA)

    # mask the matching values
    mask = np.isin(blurred_hue, matching_hues)

    # get a list of [(x, y), ...] true values in the mask
    xs, ys = np.nonzero(mask)
    return zip(xs, ys)
```

It's worth noting you may want to investigate other kinds of blur that have different properties.

**Edit:** I moved the previous solution down because I think blurring is probably going to give you better results.

One solution would be to artificially smooth/expand your `hues` list of allowed hues. In a given ROI, the hues you selected may not be continuous (for example deep blue and cyan, but not blues in between) and may cut off at an unnatural threshold.

I would suggest making `hues` into a [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) so it's a bit easier to do those kinds of manipulations. If your `hues` array looked something like `[30, 31, ..., 40, 230, 231, ..., 240]` you could smooth it with

```
import numpy as np

hues = np.array(hues)  # numpy it
blended_hues = np.concatenate([
    hues + 1, hues + 2, ...  # as many points out as you want
    hues - 1, hues - 2, ...
])
all_hues = list(np.unique(np.concatenate([hues, blended_hues])))
```

And then `all_hues` will have your original hues with some extras.

Another solution may be to look at [CIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space) color spaces. In those, usually `X` and `Y` are the hue extended into two-dimensions, so you can do more sophisticated color blending.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll try it and see how it works

Comment: Also this ```hues = set([x[0] for x in values])

 hues = np.array(hues)  # numpy it
 blended_hues = np.concatenate([
  hues + 1, hues + 2,
  hues - 1, hues - 2,
 ])
 all_hues = list(np.unique(np.concatenate([hues, blended_hues])))``` implementation throws this error ```File "/home/sam/code/pixelart/pixelart/views.py", line 430, in get_hsv_positions
    hues + 1, hues + 2,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'int'```

Comment: You would need to change the line from `hues = np.array(hues)` to `hues = np.array(list(hues))`. Numpy arrays are ordered and don't support casting directly from `set` objects. Alternatively, just drop the `set(...)` part at the beginning -- the values will be made unique by `np.unique(...)` anyway.

Comment: it works but goes a bit overboard and samples colors like her lipstick color which is alot less similar to the skin color in mind.

Comment: I added another solution that involves smoothing the hue channel. It should make matching areas a bit smoother as well.

Comment: Getting this error with your implementation `matching_hues.add(hue_channel[x, y])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: I just got a chance to check this. I mixed up the indexes on `hue_channel = hsv_image[...]`. Slicing it `[:, :, 0]` messed with the `x, y` coordinates which led to your index error. The correct order to slice numpy arrays is `[channel, row, column]` so I changed the line to `hue_channel = hsv_image[0, :, :]`. Sorry about that! [Here](http://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/index-and-slice/) is a helpful article on Numpy slicing!

Comment: It's still returning the same error `File "/home/sam/code/pixelart/pixelart/views.py", line 493, in get_color_range
    cells = get_hsv_positions_smooth(image, cells)
  File "/home/sam/code/pixelart/pixelart/views.py", line 458, in get_hsv_positions_smooth
    matching_hues.add(hue_channel[x, y])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
[09/Apr/2019 06:51:13] "POST /color-range HTTP/1.1" 500 16846`